# Execute system state reset upon unittest assertation fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing, python-unittest

I'm a bit confused regarding `unittests`. I have an embedded system I am testing from outside with Python.

The issue is that after each test is passed I need to reset the system state. However if a test fails it could leave the system in an arbitrary state I need to reset. After each test I go back to the initial state but if an assertion fails it will skip that part.

Therefore, what's the proper way to handle this situation? Some ideas I have are:

- Put each test in a `try`, `catch`, `finally` but that doesn't seem so right (`unittest` already handles test exceptions).
- Put each test in a different class and invoke `tearDown()` method at the end of it
- Call `initSystemState()` at the beggining of each test to go back to init state (but it is slower than resetting only what needs to be reset at the end of the test)

Any suggestions? Ideally if I have `testSpeed()` test there should be a `testSpeedOnStop()` function to be called at the end. Perhaps `unittest` is not the right tool for this job also as all the functions have side-effects and are working together so maybe I should lean more towards integration tests libraries which I haven't explored.

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is done in the `setUp(self)` method of the test class.

This method is **automatically called prior to each test** and provides a fresh state for each instance of the tests.

After each test, the `tearDown` method is run to possibly clean up remnants of failed tests.

You can write a `setUp / tearDowm` to be executed befora and after all tests; more elaborate tests may require stubbing or mocking objects to be build.

Comment: In this particular case a general setUp() may do the trick even if it perfoms a bit slower than only resetting the right things but as far as I know then if each test requires a different cleanUp procedure should I use them in different classes then?

Comment: I am afraid I am not sure what you mean by "should I use them in different classes then?"

Comment: If I put each test on its own class then I can write a special tearDown() method for each test to be executed at the end (not the same for all)